# Simple Predicate using AND

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format:"(a = %@) AND (b = %@)  AND (c = %@) AND (d = %@) AND (e = %@)", a1, a2, a3 ,a4 ,a5)

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "MyStuff", predicate: predicate1)
```

The above line does not work, are we allowed to use a predicate with more than 1 value on the CloudKit? This only seems to work on the first variable - `a = %@`

Comment: Have you checked that your predicate matches all the conditions listed in the [`CKQuery` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/)? Have you tried all of the different sub-predicated individually? Do you get an error message in your logs? What happens exactly? "Does not work" is really the worst possible description one could imagine.

Comment: This seems to work, the problem was with my data on the Cloud.